# using glEvalCoord with glulookat

Tags: opengl

I was wondering how to use glEvalCoord()
with gluLookAt().  I have read up on the two commands in the Programming
guide but it doesn't look like I can.  Is this true?  I was hoping to create
a spline curve and use the vertices generated as the vertices in gluLookAt().

Has anyone tried this or know if it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [OpenGL feedback mechanism](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter13.html#name2) to slurp out the vertices generated by the GL evaluators.

Though in the long run you're better off generating the spline geometry yourself.

Comment: I have tried it, but getting some problem. Can you look into that?                                                           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465576/glevalcoord-when-used-with-glfeedback-is-not-giving-output-as-expected