# How to get vertex information(X,Y) from Evaluators( created by glEvalPoint1 )

Tags: opengl, vertex, opengl-compat

I am trying to read vertex x,y information from OpenGL which are created by Evaluators. Evaluators are working fine and I can draw a Bézier curve using below code.  But I want to draw the vertices using other library for some purpose.

I am trying to draw Bézier curve in my application window without using OpenGL.  I have to draw Bézier curve with a third party library, so I will pass list X,Y values to the drawing component.  Drawing component will draw the list of points.  My plan was to get the points from OpenGL by reading the vertex information.

```
glMap1f( GL_MAP1_VERTEX_3, 0.0f, 50.0f, 3, 4, &SupportPoints[0][0] );
glMapGrid1f( 50, 0, 50 );
glBegin( GL_LINE_STRIP );
for( int nI =0; nI < 50; nI++ )
{
    glEvalPoint1(nI );
}
glEnd();
```

How can I get the vertex X,Y information generated by `glEvalPoint()`?

```
glBegin( GL_LINE_STRIP );
for( int nI =0; nI < 50; nI++ )
{
    // I need vertex information created at this point.
    glEvalPoint1(nI );
}
glEnd();
```

Is there any get function which will return the X,Y value prepared by `glEvalPoint1()`?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a [feedback](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter13.html#name2) buffer to capture the geometry before you start evaluating.  [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19504308/44729).